# Missing comma and space

Tags: excel

Its been to days I am checking this formula, intended result is **Apple, Orange, Grape
**. But got result **AppleOrange, Grape,**. Missing the comma and space and extra comma

[image]

[image]

Formula

```
=IF(A2="","",$A$1)
&IF(D2="","",$D$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),"",", ")
&IF(G2="","",$G$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2=""),"",", ")
&IF(J2="","",$J$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2=""),"",", ")
&IF(M2="","",$M$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2=""),"",", ")
&IF(O2="","",$O$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2=""),"",", ")
&IF(Q2="","",$Q$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2="",Q2=""),"",", ")
&IF(S2="","",$S$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2="",Q2="",S2=""),"",", ")
&IF(U2="","",$U$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2="",Q2="",S2="",U2=""),"",", ")
&IF(W2="","",$W$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2="",Q2="",S2="",U2="",W2=""),"",", ")
&IF(X2="","",$X$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2="",Q2="",S2="",U2="",W2="",X2),"",", ")
&IF(Y2="","",$Y$1)
&IF(OR(A2="",D2="",G2="",J2="",M2="",O2="",Q2="",S2="",U2="",W2="",X2="",Y2),"",", ")
```

**File**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4q4fv34m0tbcp3h/stack.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your logic is slightly off.  Your logic should be that, beginning with the second fruit column, Orange, you conditionally add a comma *before* that fruit name if *any* fruit previously appeared.

Consider the following portion of the formula covering Apple and Orange:

```
=IF(A2="yes", $A$1, "")
&IF(D2="yes", IF(A2="yes", ", ", "")&$D$1, "")
```

If Orange is present, we print an optional preceding comma, but *only* if something came before it, which in this case would mean that Apple were present.  Then, we print "Orange" after this optional comma.  This logic is repeated for the remainder of the columns.  All that really changes is the `OR` expression which checks for the presence of even one fruit, which is all that is required to warrant adding a comma separator.

```
=IF(A2="yes", $A$1, "")
&IF(D2="yes", IF(A2="yes", ", ", "")&$D$1, "")
&IF(G2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes"), ", ", "")&$G$1, "")
&IF(J2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes"), ", ", "")&$J$1, "")
&IF(M2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes"), ", ", "")&$M$1, "")
&IF(O2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes"), ", ", "")&$O$1, "")
&IF(Q2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes",
                    O2="yes"), ", ", "")&$Q$1, "")
&IF(S2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes",
                    O2="yes", Q2="yes"), ", ", "")&$S$1, "")
&IF(U2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes",
                    O2="yes", Q2="yes", S2="yes"), ", ", "")&$U$1, "")
&IF(W2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes",
                    O2="yes", Q2="yes", S2="yes", U2="yes"), ", ", "")&$W$1, "")
&IF(X2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes",
                    O2="yes", Q2="yes", S2="yes", U2="yes", W2="yes"), ", ", "")&$X$1, "")
&IF(Y2="yes", IF(OR(A2="yes", D2="yes", G2="yes", J2="yes", M2="yes",
                    O2="yes", Q2="yes", S2="yes", U2="yes", W2="yes",
                    X2="yes"), ", ", "")&$Y$1, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to shorten. Follow this pattern:

```
=IF(A2="","",A1&", ")&IF(D2="","",D1&", ")&IF(G2="","",G1&", ")
```

Then wrap it with this to get rid of the trailing comma:

```
=IF(RIGHT(stuff,1)=",",LEFT(stuff,LEN(stuff,-1),stuff))
```

Also, for crazy long formulas (but only when absolutely necessary) I highly recommend using an [excel beautifier](http://excelformulabeautifier.com).

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, because you are always printing a comma, even in the case where there is nothing on either side of the comma.

Comment: Although this formula slightly off, but it give me a pretty good view on other formula/way to solve it. Either way. Thank you amigo. That formula look neat.

Answer (score 1):

Edit - use this formula instead.  Similar, but you won't need the extra row:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B3:Z3,TRUE)<1,"",LEFT(CONCAT(IF(B3:Z3,$B$2:$Z$2&", ","")),LEN(CONCAT(IF(B3:Z3,$B$2:$Z$2&", ","")))-2))
```

This is better than chaining if statements, since you can easily add and subtract fruits without altering the formula.

Original answer:

Change your yes's to TRUE.  Add a row above and a column to the left.

In the row above, add your names, with a comma and space.  E.g. "Apple, "

In the left column use the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B3:Z3,TRUE)<1,"",LEFT(CONCAT(IF(B3:Z3,$B$1:$Z$1,"")),LEN(CONCAT(IF(B3:Z3,$B$1:$Z$1,"")))-2))
```

CTRL+Shift+Enter while you are editing formula will make it an array formula, which is what you need for it to work

What this is doing is:
1) Uses a blank if there are no trues
2) Adds all the title's together where you have a TRUE
3) Removes the last comma and space.

See picture.  [image]

If you really want single fruits to show as blank, then use <=1 instead of <1